# Why the function returnes NaN if the arguments are numbers?

Tags: javascript, function, nan

Function, which is for counting the n-th number of Catalan doesn't work( NaN)
First of all I wrote a function for factorial, and then function for Catalan. All the Factorials are counted right, and the type of answers is number, but when I try to make operations with them for example in my function I have a problem of NaN

```js
function factorial(n) {
  var factorial = 1
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    factorial *= i
  }
  console.log(factorial)
}

function catalan(n) {
  var catalan = factorial(2 * n)
  catalan /= factorial(n + 1)
  catalan /= factorial(n)
  console.log(catalan)
}
catalan(3)
```

Comment: Your functions don't have `return` statements.

Comment: Change `console.log(factorial)` in your factorial function to `return factorial`.

Comment: As stated before, you are not returning anything, but as a future heads up, `typeof(NaN) === 'number'`, so just because the return type is number doesn't mean it's not `NaN`

Comment: why change that console.log just write after the console.log

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you don't `return` anything from the functions.
Try this:

```
function factorial(n) {
  var factorial = 1
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    factorial *= i
  }
  console.log("In factorial: factorial="+factorial)
  return factorial
}

function catalan(n) {
  var catalan = factorial(2 * n)
  catalan /= factorial(n + 1)
  catalan /= factorial(n)
  console.log("In catalan: catalan="+catalan)
  return catalan
}
catalan(3)
```

In my console, I see:

```
In factorial: factorial=720
In factorial: factorial=24
In factorial: factorial=6
In catalan: catalan=5
5
```

Comment: Did this solve your code?
If so: can you select my answer?